# Delete a record from a RecordStore

Tags: java-me, midp, rms

I want to delete  one record from a RecordStore each time I use this code ,that means the second time when user see the records he shouldn't see the deleted record, but that doesn't happen.

After  testing my code same records on the recordStore founded. !!!

These are  records I entered.

_1_Elhadi_**_Sun Jan 26 01:00:00 GMT+03:00 2014**

_A_John_***Sun Jan 26 01:00:00 GMT+03:00 2014***

_3_Smith_***Sun Jan 26 01:00:00 GMT+03:00 2014***

```
public void deleteRecStore(String recID) {

try
 {
 recordStore.openRecordStore("recordStore", true)   ;
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
 try
 {

 RecordEnumeration e = recordStore.enumerateRecords(null,null,false);

 int found = -1;

 while (e.hasNextElement()) 
 {

 int id = e.nextRecordId();

 String next = new String(e.toString());

 int fee = next.indexOf("_", 1);

 **// These statements don't print anything** 

System.out.print("next.indexOf" +next.indexOf("_", 1));


System.out.println( "next.substring(1, fee)"+"\t" +next.substring(fee, 1));

System.out.println("recID"+"\t"+recID);

if (next.substring(1, fee).equals(recID))

{

found = id ;

}
  }
if (found == -1)

{

System.out.println("not found!");
}
else
{
recordStore.deleteRecord(found);
}
   }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
 ex.printStackTrace();
 }
     }
```

Comment: @AliPour Can you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is this line:

```
String next = new String(e.toString());
```

Looks like you're converting your RecordEnumeration object into a String object, and trying to find the record id in that string. That won't get you far.

Try replacing that line with this line and see if it helps:

```
String next = new String(recordStore.getRecord(id));
```

Comment: thank for response. but Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem .